# Django queryset - column IN() GROUP BY HAVING COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: django, group-by, distinct, django-orm, having

With the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = "posts"

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)

   class Meta:
       db_table = "tags"

class PostTag(models.Model):
    postid = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    tagid = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("postid", "tagid")
        db_table = "posttags"
```

To get postids of posts which contain **all** the tagids given in TAGLIST where TAGLEN is the number of tagids in TAGLIST:

```
SELECT postid
FROM posttags
WHERE tagid IN (TAGLIST)
GROUP BY postid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tagid) = TAGLEN
```

But how do I do this with Django ORM?

Comment: why you are not using foreignkey, and BTW [this](http://setthecode.pythonanywhere.com/post?id=19) post is good for taginput :)

Comment: `posttag.objects.get(tagid__icontains=you_list).postid` this will return the post id for a posttag that contains a tag in your list

Comment: @mohammedqudah: but it should contain **all** the tags.

Comment: @mohammedqudah I thought about using foreign keys but I decided against it because of how many there might be.

Comment: Don't forget to read about the tagsinput : )

Comment: @mohammedqudah Thanks, I might use that taginput link. Also your answer doesn't work because it doesn't consider if the post contains **all** the tagids in TAGLIST. I forgot to mention that TAGLIST contains tagids and I already know how to get TAGLIST and TAGLEN.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

```
    TAGLEN = TAGLIST.count()
    withtags = PostTag.objects.filter(tagid__in=TAGLIST)
    withall = withtags.values("postid").annotate(tagtotal=Count("tagid", distinct=True)).order_by()
    withall.filter(tagtotal=TAGLEN).values_list("postid", flat=True)
```

And running `.query.__str__()` on all this returns basically the following SQL below.

```
SELECT "postid"
FROM "posttags"
WHERE "tagid" IN (TAGLIST)
GROUP BY "postid"
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "tagid") = TAGLEN'
```

Comment: Recommend any improvements.