# How to write postgre query in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I am trying to fetch user id who has multiple skill. below is the postgre query which is giving me correct result, I m stuck while implementing the same in Django.

```
SELECT "Extractor_usr_skills"."user_id"
FROM "Extractor_usr_skills" WHERE "Extractor_usr_skills"."skill_id" 
IN (356, 360) GROUP BY "Extractor_usr_skills"."user_id" HAVING COUNT("Extractor_usr_skills"."user_id") = 2
```

I am able to do this by following ([Django queryset - column IN() GROUP BY HAVING COUNT DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304612/django-queryset-column-in-group-by-having-count-distinct) ). Do we have any better solutions?

```
class Usr_Details(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    exp = models.FloatField(max_length=9, blank=True)
    education = models.CharField(max_length=110, blank=True)
    college = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    currentEmployer = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)


class Skills(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)


class Usr_Skills(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Usr_Details', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey('Skills', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Show your relevant models

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I have edited the questions with models

Comment: Hey, Django has ORM [Documation Link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#making-queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
from django.db.models import Count

result = Usr_Skills.objects.values('user')\
        .annotate(skill_count = Count('skill'))\
        .filter(skill_count__gt=1)\
        .values('user') # Or .values('user.id')
```

Answer (score -1):

Django have ORM, try to interface with your db with it, its secure